# What is the string diagram for the Bimonad law

Tags: category-theory, monads

We have [string diagrams](http://inspirehep.net/record/1231010/files/fig_Frobenius_alg_obj_axioms_2.png) that succinctly describe the Frobenius law.  Is there a string diagram that describes the Bimonad law?  Bimonads are (co)monads that have a mixed  distributive law.  They were described by [WISBAUER and MESABLISHVILI](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.1163.pdf)

Comment: Check out [this nCategory Cafe](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2017/02/distributive_laws.html) post for string diagrams giving distributive laws, if that helps.